# Filter CSV in scala?

Tags: scala, csv

I have code to read a CSV like this:

```
def readCSV(fileName: String, filter: String) =
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)
    .getLines
    .map(_.split("\t"))
    .map(a ⇒ MyClass(a(0), a(1), a(2).toInt, a(3).toDouble))
    .toIndexedSeq
```

I want to filter that list based on a value in the CSV, for example if the last column is "T" then I want to be able to pass in "T" for filter and have only that collection.

Comment: Haha, Yea, it's tab delimited not comma despite the CSV.  The only thing that matters is that it's delimited with something...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "T"? Is it a type, or a specific value? And what collection do you expect to get out at the end in this case? Eg. filter for column T set to "true", or a value > 5, or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `map` you're getting a collection of arrays (which BTW you have to split not by tabs but by commas). You can then filter by checking the values of this array. For example,

`map(_.split(",")).filter(_.last == "T"). ...`